# Chef-solo install - gecode compile error

Tags: installation, centos, chef-infra, yum

Im trying to install chef-solo on CentOS 6.3 x64 and when I run:

```
sudo chef-solo -c /etc/chef/solo.rb -j ~/chef.json -r http://s3.amazonaws.com/chef-solo/bootstrap-latest.tar.gz
```

I'm getting this output:

```
g++ -I. -ffast-math -fno-strict-aliasing -O3 -fvisibility=hidden -ggdb -pipe -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -pthread -DNDEBUG   \
    -c -o gecode/int/extensional.o  gecode/int/extensional.cpp
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/chef-solo/gecode-3.5.0'
STDERR: {standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:13822: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
{standard input}:14946: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.'
{standard input}:14946: Error: open CFI at the end of file; missing .cfi_endproc directive
g++: Internal error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report.
See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
make[1]: *** [gecode/int/extensional.o] Error 1
make: *** [compilelib] Error 2
---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20120904-19809-1ofhwoq" ----
Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20120904-19809-1ofhwoq" returned 2
```

I can install gecode from the RBEL6 repo without any problems but the cookbook attempts to install from source. I found [this](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/gecode/pull/1) pull request on github which attempts to install from the RBEL repo but I got an error saying that the repository metadata couldn't be found. Anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 4):

Since I have been searching for an answer to this, my findings were rather ... unsurprising.

I simply ran out of memory. I had to compile my files on another system with the same OS (copied over /tmp/chef-solo/gecode-3.5.0 to the box and just ran make) and synced the resulting folder back to run *make install*

Once the library is found the compile step is skipped and you should be good to continue.

Comment: since this came up as google search result for me on the problem, thought I'd help a few by backing up your statement: https://github.com/opscode/dep-selector-libgecode/issues/15